# Correcting formatting for framed theorems

Tags: formatting, mdframed, amsthm

I have been using the following code to create overhang for my theorems (and other theorem-like environments) for a while now.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\newlength{\marginlabelsep}\setlength{\marginlabelsep}{1em}
\newtheoremstyle{thmoverhang} %% Name
{} 
{}
{\sffamily}
{} 
{\bfseries}
{} 
{0pt}
{\vtop to 0pt{\hbox to -\marginlabelsep{\hss\thmname{#1}}
        \hbox to -\marginlabelsep{\hss\thmnumber{#2}}}\thmnote{#3\\}%
}
\theoremstyle{thmoverhang}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
```

(In fact, it was contributed by another user on this site, but that's besides the point.) I recently wanted to add a box around theorems I deem important using the package `\mdframed`, like this

```
\newenvironment{fthm}{\begin{mdframed}\begin{thm}}{\end{thm}\end{mdframed}\vspace{-0.3cm}
```

but this causes a problem, where the box does not contain the **Theorem** and the counter (see picture below). How can I make the box bigger to contain both the description of the theorem and the theorem title and counter? In addition, is it possible to lift the upper border of the box; it seems too low and the top and bottom padding of the text within the box seems unequal.  Any input is appreciated!

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength{\marginlabelsep}\setlength{\marginlabelsep}{1em}
\newtheoremstyle{thmoverhang} %% Name
{} 
{}
{\sffamily}
{} 
{\bfseries}
{} 
{0pt}
{\vtop to 0pt{\hbox to -\marginlabelsep{\hss\thmname{#1}}
        \hbox to -\marginlabelsep{\hss\thmnumber{#2}}}\thmnote{#3\\}%
}
\theoremstyle{thmoverhang}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\newenvironment{fthm}{ \begin{mdframed}\begin{thm} }{ \end{thm}\end{mdframed}\vspace{-0.3cm} }

\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\begin{document}
    \begin{fthm}
    Theorem Description Theorem Description Theorem Description Theorem Description
    \end{fthm}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: for raising the rule at the top, you can put `\strut` into the `\hbox` part of the `thmoverhang` definition just before the `#2`.  getting the box outline to cover the number portion requires more work (and thought); no time for that right now.

Answer (score 1):

With `tcolorbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}%<--- for testing purpose only
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newcounter{myth}
\tcbset{
    commonopt/.style={
        enhanced,
        enhanced jigsaw,
        breakable, 
        sharp corners,
        left=80pt,
        fontupper=\itshape,
        opacityback=0,
        boxrule=1pt,
        text width=\linewidth,
        oversize,
        },
    }
  
\tikzset{
    titlenode/.style={
        anchor=north west, 
        font=\bfseries, 
        text width=66pt, 
        inner sep=3mm+1pt, 
        align=right
    }
  }

\newtcolorbox[use counter=myth]{thm}[2][]{%
    commonopt,
    opacityframe=0,
    overlay={\node[titlenode] at (frame.north west) {\vphantom{p}Theorem~\themyth\ #2};},
    #1
}

\newtcolorbox[use counter=myth]{fthm}[2][]{%
    commonopt,
    before skip=14pt plus 2pt minus 2pt,
    after skip=14pt plus 2pt minus 2pt,
    overlay={\node[titlenode] at (frame.north west) {\vphantom{p}Theorem~\themyth\ #2};},
    #1
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

Theorem \ref{th:nofnot} is with no frame and no title, only with theorem number.
\begin{thm}[label=th:nofnot]{}
    Theorem Description Theorem Description Theorem Description Theorem Description
\end{thm}
Theorem \ref{th:nofyest} is with no frame but with title, other than number.
\begin{thm}[label=th:nofyest]{(Pythagoras)}
    Theorem Description Theorem Description Theorem Description Theorem Description
\end{thm}
Theorem \ref{th:yesfnot} is with frame but without title, only number.
\begin{fthm}[label=th:yesfnot]{}
    Theorem Description Theorem Description Theorem Description Theorem Description
\end{fthm}
Theorem \ref{th:yesfyest} is with frame, title and number.
\begin{fthm}[label=th:yesfyest]{(Pythagoras)}
    Theorem Description Theorem Description Theorem Description Theorem Description
\end{fthm}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]